# active directory error server is unwilling to perform

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am using below code but iam keep getting '**server is unwilling to perform**' , not at all understanding what to change in the code. My code everything seems good. Please tell me if anything has to be changed.

```
$cfg = $this->app->config;
$ad = new Ldap("ldaps://" . $cfg['ad']['server']);

$ad->set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$ad->set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$b = $ad->bind($cfg['ad']['binddn'], $cfg['ad']['bindpassword']);

$r = $ad->search($cfg['ad']['user_basedn'],"sAMAccountName=".$this->uid);
$dn = $r[0]["dn"];

$newPassword = "\"" . $password . "\"";
$len = strlen($newPassword);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
$newPassw .= "{$newPassword{$i}}\000";}
$newPassword = $newPassw;
$userdata["unicodePwd"] = $newPassword;
$userdata["pwdLastSet"] = -1;
$userdata["userAccountControl"] = 512;
$result = $ad->mod_replace($dn , $userdata);

$ad_error = $ad->error();
$ad_error_no = $ad->errno(); // here getting 53
```

Comment: Does anyone know this?

Comment: Can't tell from your code listing but are you attempting a password change over an open port (i.e. 389)? If so, by default AD will not permit that.